# Android Studio 'Find in Files' search: How to disable the 'Too Many Results' dialog?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Android Studio Find files in project and show dialog said too many result may cause oom, how to avoid this?

[image]

I tried to do theses steps, but nothing happens

1. Settings
2. Advanced Settings
3. Maximum number of results to show in Find In Path/Show Usages preview
4. Change to 1000

Answer (score 1):

No way to do it at the moment I'm afraid.

Related bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-285780

As for the advanced option that you mentioned, it only affects the number of results shown in the *preview area of the 'Find in Files' popup dialog*, not total n of results in the Find Window, which is what the "Too many results found" dialog actually reflects.